# AssertionError: Arrays are not equal

Tags: python, error-handling, scikit-learn, compiler-errors

I am developing a new classifier and following the scikit-learn template.

I am at the step where I am checking my estimator, using the code below from the template:

```
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
check_estimator(my_classifier)
```

When I ran the above code, I am getting an error. Parts of the error below:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py in check_classifiers_predictions(X, y, name, classifier_orig)
   1762         # For some specific cases 'ComplementNB' predicts less classes
   1763         # than expected
-> 1764         assert_array_equal(np.unique(y), np.unique(y_pred))
   1765     assert_array_equal(classes, classifier.classes_,
   1766                        err_msg="Unexpected classes_ attribute for %r: "

AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(shapes (3,), (2,) mismatch)
 x: array(['one', 'three', 'two'], dtype='<U5')
 y: array(['one', 'three'], dtype='<U5')
```

My classifier is a binary classifier. Can anyone point me to a direction on this? Many thanks.

Comment: please add code of `my_classifier`

Comment: The code is really long, is it still possible to post it here? I have tested the code with example datasets and it ran without any errors. I suspect its something to do with the variable names for classes in my code (maybe y, classes_) clashing with the variable names in check_estimator

Comment: one thing is for sure, we can't help you without a [mcve]

Comment: Does moderators here allow posting of really long codes?